# Время жизни статичной переменной Java

Tags: java, android

Если сделать класс Config и определить в нем несколько `static` переменных (не `final`). Какого будет время их жизни? 
В данном случае использую Android-приложение. Будут ли живы переменные при переходе с активити на активити или например при свернутом приложении не придется их заново инициализировать?

Comment: при переходе между активити будут жить. После сворачивания - не факт - система может прибить приложение.

Comment: Возьмем идеальную ситуацию. Когда после сворачивания оно нормально разворачивается. Вообще есть такая практика, хранить часто изменяющиеся данные в static?

Comment: я бы рассматривал идеальную ситуацию, когда после сворачивания система убивает приложение сразу.

Я в static рекомендую хранить константы. А хранить сложные объекты (а тем более любые объекты, которые связаны с gui - например, адаптеры) - ни в коем случае.

Answer (score 2):

Если хотите хранить переменные в статике используйте `Singleton`. он будет жив до тех пор, пока приложение совсем не будет выкинуто и памяти. Вообще хранить динамичные значения в `static` не лучшая практика в Android.